# Number pattern challenge

Tags: pattern

Given the following:

> 17161 = 1
>   22135 = 0
>   50213 = 1
>   88888 = 10
>   49321 = 1
>   22222 = 0
>   00000 = 5
>   71132 = 0
>   96784 = 4
>   29381 = 3
>   79797 = 2
>   89104 = 4
>   91325 = 0
>   35720 = 1
>   67812 = 3
>   23692 = 2

What is 59682 = ?

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

> 4

Explanation:

> Just count the circles in each number! (4 isn't counted, because it's not circle)